# Gradle task overriding environment spring profile

Tags: spring, gradle, build.gradle

I have a task in my `build.gradle`:

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
  systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "postgres"
  testLogging {
      events = ["passed", "failed", "skipped"]
  }
  filter {
      includeTestsMatching "foo.bar.integration.*"
  }
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and want my spring application to run with the `postgres` profile when I run `./gradlew integrationTest` however it runs with a `test` profile instead.

What is causing gradle to override my spring profile setting?

Comment: here this property is only being passed to the junit runner ; check the Test class for any annotation override or if you are starting the spring-boot main-class  in a different way

Comment: @PrasadU is correct, I had `@ActiveProfiles("test")` on my integration test classes which was overriding whatever I set.